# Generating audio at input of AudioSource

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I would like to generate audio at the input of an `AudioSource` in Unity.

I have tried using the [`OnAudioFilterRead()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnAudioFilterRead.html) MonoBehaviour but this only allows you to alter the audio data *after* the `AudioSource`, which bypasses any spatialisation/pitching/gain etc on the `AudioSource` component.

I also had the idea of using an `AudioClip` as a buffer, filling it with the audio data and then loading that into the `AudioSource`, but I don't think this could be done without knowing the buffer size and being able to load a new clip as each buffer is read. There is no method to read into the `AudioClip` as each new buffer is required.

Is there any way to change the audio data of `AudioSource` *before* it goes through the audio source's spatialisation/pitching/gain etc?

Comment: This is not off topic and doesn't ask to 'recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource'. It is a direct question about Unity. If anything is unclear then please comment and I will edit for clarity, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this myself. It was a silly mistake. After reading the Docs for `OnAudioFilterRead` properly I found that it states:

> The audio data is an array of floats ranging from [-1.0f;1.0f] and
>   contains audio from the previous filter in the chain or the AudioClip
>   on the AudioSource. If this is the first filter in the chain and a
>   clip isn't attached to the audio source this filter will be 'played'.
>   That way you can use the filter as the audio clip, procedurally
>   generating audio.

I had an audio clip in the `AudioSource` which stopped the `OnFilterRead` being the first process in the DSP chain. Removing the audio clip fixed the problem!